# Slick query with one to many relationship

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using slick 3.2.3 and I'm trying to build a query that returns a `Seq[Entity1, Seq[Entity2]]` for two entities that have a one to many relationship (for each Entity1 are associated multiple Entity2).

So I have my two entities

```
case class Entity1(name: String, id: Option[Long] = None)
case class Entity2(entity1Id: Long, name: String, id: Option[Long] = None
```

with the table definitions (that are generated by slick codegen task)

```
class entity1Table(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[Entity1](_tableTag, "ENTITY_1") {
   ...
}
lazy val groupTable = new TableQuery(tag => new groupTable(tag))

class entity2Table(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[Entity2](_tableTag, "ENTITY_2") {
   ...
}
lazy val entity2Table = new TableQuery(tag => new entity2Table(tag))
```

Reading [this article](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/has-many-relationships-slick) I've created a query like this

```
val q = (for {
  e1 <- entity1Table
  e2 <- entity2Table if e2.entity1Id === e1.id
} yield (e1, e2)).groupBy(_._1) map {
  case (entity1, tuples) => (entity1, tuples.map(_._2))
}

db.run(q.result)
```

but I get this error at compile time:

```
Error:(19, 35) No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection,
 you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
 or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.
  Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
     Source type: (my.namespace.models.entity1Table, slick.lifted.Query[my.namespace.models.entity2Table,my.namespace.models.Entity2,[+A]Seq[A]])
   Unpacked type: T
     Packed type: G
    } yield (e1, e2)).groupBy(_._1) map {
```

I suspect that it cannot map the entity1Table and entity2Table.

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [Slick doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#aggregation), `groupBy` currently doesn't support executing a query with nested values of type `Query`:

> The intermediate query (i.e. the query ended with groupBy() without an
>   aggregate function) contains nested values of type Query. These would
>   turn into nested collections when executing the query, which is not
>   supported at the moment. Therefore it is necessary to flatten the
>   nested queries immediately by aggregating their values (or individual
>   columns)

In other words, your Slick `groupBy` query must be coupled with an aggregate function equivalent to SQL's `count()`, `sum()`, etc.  For example, the following query which is equivalent to `select count(*) ... group by ... having count(*) > 1` would work:

```
val query = ( for {
    e1 <- entity1Table
    e2 <- entity2Table if e2.entity1Id === e1.id
  } yield (e1, e2)
).
groupBy(_._1).map{
  case (entity1, group) => (entity1, group.size)
}.
filter(_._2 > 1)
```

Comment: Reading the documentation it seems you are right, currently what I wanto to obtain is not supported.
Thank you.